# CSS/Javascript to detect broken image, and hide parent div

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div class="A">
   <a href="abc"><img class="A" alt=" " src="/1.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I need a javascript to detect if image broken,make div height to 0px,basically to hide it.
Or are there any css to do it?

```
<script> $('.A').find('img').length == 0){
       $(this).hide();

    }</script>
```

Comment: by broken image do you mean that the image is not found?

Comment: yes thats what i meant

Comment: from what i understand you cannot poll the server using JS and check if the image is present or not , for that we have server side languages like php.

Answer (score 4):

The exact code you are searching for is something like this:

```
<div class="A">
    <a href="abc"><img src="/1.jpg" onerror="this.parentNode.style.display='none'" class="A" alt=" " /></a>
</div>
```

The error event in the `img` tag makes its parent node `div` to be hidden. This should work.

Answer (score 3):

To check if an image has completely loaded, you can check if it is complete like this:

```
$.ready(function(){
    //I'm guessing that's how find() works, correct me if I'm wrong
    if($('.A').find("img")[0].complete){

            console.log("successfully loaded!")
      }else{
           $('.A').find("div")[0].hide();
      }
}
```

A pure JS Solution is:

```
document.onload=function(){
    if(document.getElementById("image").complete){
        console.log("complete")
    }else{
        document.getElementById("imgwrap").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that need to be inside a document.ready()? Otherwise it might run the javascript before the image has finished loading - OP wants to check whether it is broken, not whether it is incomplete.

Comment: hi, do you mind to give example based on the given html? i couldn't figure out what to replace in the code above,thanks

Comment: @AnnaBoyle that should do it, but I'm not too familiar with jQuery, so correct me if that's not how to correctly find the element.

Comment: @scrblnrd3 im not using jquery, i need javascript :)

Comment: @AnnaBoyle What? You have jQuery in your question!

Comment: @scrblnrd3 im a newbie,im confused with both, thats y i need help, and please kindly read my question tq

Comment: @AnnaBoyle jQuery is a library for Javascript. I can post a pure JS solution if you want

Comment: and actually i need it to run through the whole page as there are a lot of images of same class